# Turn black pixel on the first image to white if it is also black on a second co-located image

Tags: image, rgb

I have 2 co-located images, both created in a similar way and both have the size of 7,221 x 119 pixels.

I want to write a logic like this:

If the R,G,B values of a certain pixel (called it x) in image 1 = 0,0,0 (black) And the R,G,B values of pixel x in image 2 = 0,0,0 (black) then change the R,G,B values of pixel x in image 1 to 255,255,255 (white), Else no change.

How can I do this in either Matlab or Python?

Comment: If the images are in png format, [pypng](http://pythonhosted.org/pypng/index.html) should provide all the functionality you need.

Comment: Just one pixel?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Using a good interface, which give you the pixels (e.g. using scikit-image) makes this trivial! Something else: jpg is the worst input-format imaginable for this task. You might need to reformulate your logic/comparison to make it more robust. As these are lossy compressed, the colors change (not saved as RGB). This (maybe) makes your logic faulty. (example: pic A and B designed by you; compress as jpg; do your stuff and you will see some pixels get not recognized (as both 0) despite the fact, that they should; because of information-loss due to jpg-compression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this in python with the Pillow package.  You need to load the two pixels, check if all the color channels are `0` and if so make them `255`, then save the image again.  In Python `0` is interpreted as `False`, so `not any(vals)` will be `True` when `vals` includes only zeros.

```
from PIL import Image

im1 = Image.open("image1.jpg")
im2 = Image.open("image2.jpg")

pixel = (0, 0)
newcolor = (255,)*3
if not any(im1.getpixel(pixel)) and not any(im2.getpixel(pixel)):
    im1.putpixel(pixel, newcolor)
im1.save('image1conv.jpg')
```

Note that `not any(im1.getpixel(pixel)) and not any(im2.getpixel(pixel))` could be rewritten as `not any(im1.getpixel(pixel) + im2.getpixel(pixel))`, but I think the first way has clearer logic.

Comment: Thanks. The code does run, but when I save the new image it looks similar to the old one? I'm quite sure there are sections on 2 images that have black pixels.

Comment: @AnhNguyen: As sascha explained, jpg is a poor format for this task.  Due to how its compression works, it often doesn't faithfully preserve exact colors.  So the areas of "black" probably aren't completely black, if they are black at all, and the resulting white likely won't be pure white.  Also, the algorithm I provided is designed to work with individual pixels, which is what your question asked.  There are more efficient ways to deal with large number of pixels.

Comment: Yeah sorry I just figured out. I don't just want 1 pixel. I need to loop through the image (7,221 x 119 pixels), find all the black pixels and turn them into white if the same pixels are also black in image 2.

Comment: @AnhNguyen Did you read and understand my comment above about jpg? You could introduce the loop you need (modifying TheBlackCat's code) for treating all pixels with maybe 3 lines. But think about the problem! It migh be much better, to convert the image to grayscale, introduce a threshold (meaning < threshold = black) and filter with this threshold. Of course that's an easy modification to the code above! I also would like that you react to the comments. If you would have reacted to Marks comment, TheBlackCat already had would have given you code analysing all pixels (which was not clear).

Comment: Sorry I can only handle 1 comment at a time and I'm not a coder so I don't stay online 24 hours. Thanks for the advice. I sort of understand what you just said, but I'm not familiarized with how to do it on python. Are you suggesting this way using the threshold in Matlab image toolbox?

Comment: @AnhNguyen: At this point you should really make an entirely new question.  The original question and what you now say you need are completely different, relying on different tools and different approaches.

Comment: I got it done thanks for the help. Will also try the threshold as you suggested, @sascha